# app.config exception SqlConnection without connection string

Tags: c#, .net, app-config, sqlconnection

Here is my problem: I have a simple C# console app and I open my connection with

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=server;" + "Initial Catalog=database;" + "User id=sa;" + "Password=pass;timeout=60;");
```

That works fine. I added the app.config with some keys in the AppSettings. That works fine too.

But if I add a new tag to the config, the previous code gives me exception...why?!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="template" value="value"/>
    <add key="saveas" value="value"/>
  </appSettings>
  <tag>

  </tag>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What is the exception you are receiving?

Comment: Sounds like you haven't extended ConfigurationElement...?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but why are you concatenating strings to build your connection string? A connection string builder is probably a better idea: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-builders

Comment: You can't add arbitrary tags like that unless you declare a custom configuration section

Comment: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' has generated an exception

Comment: It would be helpful if you told us what exception its throwing, and what the Message is for that exception, and any inner exceptions.

Comment: @elle0087 that's not an exception. That's only part of the message. Post your code and the full exception, including its call stack. You can get this very easily with `Exception.ToString()`. There's nothing wrong with connection strings or appsettings which means the problem is in the code

Comment: @elle0087 btw if you add a random tag to `app.config` the application will throw an exception - the application doesn't know how to read the random tag. If you *ignore* it (eg with a `catch{}`) and try to use any value from the settings you'll get nulls.

Comment: the exception i wrote is what the catch give me...about the tag...is not possible to add a tag out AppSettings?

Comment: @elle0087 You really need to *pay attention* to what people are telling you. You're asking questions that have already been answered. You can't arbitrary tags unless you declare a custom configuration section. And you are not including all the details of the exception, which Panagiotis showed you how to obtain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just add a random tag to your config file. The config file is parsed by the runtime and the runtime has to understand it.

If you want to do something with your custom tag, it might be helpful to ask a question about that (make sure you search existing questions before you do), because there are different ways to reach what you want (for example custom configuration sections). But until then, the quickest solution to make your problem go away is to simply delete the `tag` tag from your configuration file.

Comment: @mason I don't think I did make it sound that way, but I added clarification just to make sure it really doesn't say so.

Comment: @mason Then I really cannot help, sorry. I'm pretty sure it says "there are different ways to reach what you want (for example custom configuration sections)" right there in my answer. Care to write a better one if you find another wording more appropriate?

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure how you plug your connection string into your data handler.  If you are using Linq, your project should have updated with the connection settings in the app.config automatically.  I update my app.config during publication.

Here is a sample of what my config looks like.  perhaps it will give you what you need.  You can see how I added my own "tag" called ConnectivityDatabase and SysDatabase.

[image: Snip of xml]

Comment: This does not address the problem of this question. The problem is the arbritrary `<tag>` added to the app.config which makes it unreadable.

Comment: right, so my point is to add his tag as an app settings key.  So instead of Tag, He should create his own entry in appSettings and read his data from that section instead of creating his own key.  That's why I posted a sample so he could see.  I just thought instead of saying you can't do that, i would show how to achieve what it looks like he is trying to do.